# Symfony 3.4 - how would one pass Swiftmailer into an event listener?

Tags: symfony, event-listener, swiftmailer

I'm building an e-commerce app using Stripe.  I currently have several event listeners that talk to Stripe via its API when certain things happen (e.g. a `Customer`, `Product`, or `SKU` getting created or updated).  Because these API calls can produce several `Exceptions`, I'd like to have the app email me in certain cases.

So, how would I configure my `services.yml` to pass Swiftmailer to my listeners?  My current setup (single example, but they all more or less look like this):

```
AppBundle\EventListener\UserHandler:
        arguments:
            $stripeKey: "%secret_stripe_key%"
            $session: "@session"
            $logger: "@monolog.logger"
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```

Is the resource tag simply "@swiftmailer"?  And what namespace(s) should I be using in my listeners?

Comment: arguments: ['@mailer']

Comment: Just use autowire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested above, I would use autowiring. This will prevent you from having to add code to your services.yml and is the way to go as of Symfony 3.3.

In your constructor of UserHandler:

```
__construct(Swift_Mailer $mailer, SessionInterface $session, LoggerInterface $logger) {
  $this->mailer = $mailer;
  $this->logger = $logger;
  $this->session = $session;
}
```

So in your functions you can now call `$this->mailer` which will be autowired because of the typehinting in the constructor. Same goes for Session & Logger. To find out which service you're looking for you can execute the following: `bin/console debug:autowiring`

**Make sure you include the classes above in the use-statements**